# Datasets and DataRelations

Tags: dataset

If I have two related tables in a Dataset( 2 tables and a DataRelation). Do I have to load each table with its dataadapter or is there a way to load one table and have all related tables load automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load each table with the its adapter Fill method, but you can update both with Update method if you have relation between them.